# Why is ImageSource allowed as a WPF Resource?

Tags: wpf, resources

Why does this line in a ResourceDictionary not result in a compile-error?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ImageSource x:Key="aKey">SomePath</ImageSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

My understanding was that this would result in an instance of ImageSource being created using the default ctor. This would be followed by setting all the specified properties.

However ImageSource is an abstract class - so why doesn't this result in a compile error?

Comment: Great question, look forward to someone answering this.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my guess is that the resource manager knows the concrete type of each resource. It creates an instance of the resource specified and only if it did not derive from ImageSource would a run-time exception occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this bit of XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Window x:Key="aKey">BlogHeader.jpg</Window>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource aKey}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It compiles just fine, but when you run it you get a runtime XamlParseException:

*Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Source' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'.*

If you try using a simple type instead of `Window`, for example:

```
public class SomeType
{
}
```

You will get a compile-time error:

*The Element type 'WpfApplication1.SomeClass' does not have an associated TypeConverter to parse the string 'BlogHeader.jpg'*

So the answer lies in the `TypeConverter` provided by `ImageSource` which is `ImageSourceConverter`. The magic happens in `ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom` which takes a string, creates an `Uri` from it, and uses `BitmapFrame.Create` to create a `BitmapFrame` which is derived from `ImageSource`.

Note that I used `Window` in the first example only to use a type that provides a type converter from a string.

Comment: TypeConverters are used to convert a string representation of a value to the specific type required by a property. The above explanation accounts for the Image.Source property... My question was about the ImageSource tag  - i.e. creating an instance of an abstract class (to be stored as a resource) - how is it able to create an instance of an ImageSource so that it can proceed with setting the specified properties ?

Comment: It does explain it. The Image.Source propery is only there to make sure it gets instantiated. It's gets created through ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom just as I explained. I'm not making it up, I followed the source trail.

Comment: Btw, I provided the two examples and their exception/error messages only to show the path that led me to discovering how it worked. I don't think that is clear in the text.

Comment: @Gishu: Tergiver is correct. `TypeConverters` can be associated with classes and properties, if there is a type converter associated with an abstract class and the parser encounters the type in XAML that type converter will be used to create a concrete instance.